# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

Chasing my tail trying to figure this out, googling it just leads to far more complicated examples.

I've joined two tables, which join fine.  Prof has asked us to list rows from the orders table where shipped date is NULL, or in the words of the exercise, 'orders that have not shipped yet.'

Join works fine until I add the IS NULL line and then I get the error:
**Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.**

I've written this 20 different ways and spent the afternoon googling it but can't get rid of the error.  I know it's going to be something simple but...

```
SELECT
    customers.customer_id,
    customers.name,
    customers.phone,
    orders.order_id,
    orders.order_date,
    orders.shipped_date
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    orders.shipped_date IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id=orders.customer_id
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a defined order of how to compose a query

```
select
from
join
where
group by
having
order by
```

You cannot mix that order.

Answer (score 6):

`LEFT JOIN` should come first before the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT  customers.customer_id,
        customers.name,
        customers.phone,
        orders.order_id,
        orders.order_date,
        orders.shipped_date
FROM    orders 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN customers 
            ON customers.customer_id=orders.customer_id
WHERE   orders.shipped_date IS NULL
```

For additional information about joins, see

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify LEFT JOIN, Every record on the "LEFT" side (from source) regardless of a match in the right side (joined to)

So, if you were to SWAP, for example, give me all customers REGARDLESS of having an order on file, you would do something like

```
Select
      C.Customer_ID,
      C.Name,
      C.Phone,
      O.Order_Date
   from
      Customers C
         LEFT JOIN Orders O
            on C.Customer_ID = O.Customer_ID
```

would show all customers, and if an order existed, would show that date too.

What you are looking for is just a list of all orders that have not been shipped AND who the order was for.  This would be a standers INNER JOIN as you are expecting a match to exist on BOTH sides.

```
Select
      C.Customer_ID,
      C.Name,
      C.Phone,
      O.Order_Date
   from 
      Orders O
         INNER JOIN Customers C
            on O.Customer_ID = C.Customer_ID
   where
      O.Shipped_Date IS NULL
```

So the WHERE clause in this case is explicitly on the primary "FROM" table source "Orders" (aliased as just "O").  And you only want those that have NOT shipped, thus only care about O.Shipped_Date is NULL